# How can I disable "ConnectedPDF"? (When Foxit PDF Cloud is unwanted)

Tags: windows, security, cloud, foxit-reader, terminal-server

#### Abstract

Since Version 8 the Foxit Reader every user gets this **Starupscreen and is urged** to connect to the PDF Cloud.

This feature is **unwanted on our customers terminal servers** (and, as I suspect, on the most comercial used systems.)

[image]

I found a way that seems to disable the function, but I'm unsure if it is correct. And I found **no way** to do it centrally for all user.

#### Current Successes

- Disabled the `Foxit Reader Service`

  - **Result:** The ConectedPDF seems not to be available any more, but every user gets an UAC dialog when starting Foxit. After canceling the dialog, Foxit can be used regulary.
- Disabled the plugins `Cloud Reading` and `ConnectedPDF` for one affected user.

  - **Result:** The UAC doesn't come any more. Foxit works.

#### Question(s)

- Is this the correct way to disable ConnectedPDF?
- If so, is there any way to disable the plugins for all users on the terminal server?

Answer (score 2):

It would seem that deselecting "show start page" under File/ Preferences/ General/ Application Startup gets rid of that annoying ConnectedPDF nonsense. (I call it nonsense but it is of course yet another scam to take ownership of our data.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question isn't about how to disable it once, but how to disable it on `terminal servers`for all users. Look at: **Current Successes** and **Question(s)** in my post.

Comment: and in case you are on Linux, remove or rename the fxplugins folder, to be found in your foxit installation folder: mv fxplugins fxplugins.bad

Answer (score 0):

I found this on Foxit's own site. I'll reproduce it here in case the link ever breaks.

Basically, you have 2 choices.

> #### For End Users
>
> **Manually Disabling cPDF specific plugins**
>
> 1. Open Foxit program, go to Help menu > About Foxit Plug-Ins, find dedicated plugins “ ConnectedPDF DRM, CPDFOCLink and ConnectedPDF”,
>      click on the disable icon to disable them.
> 2. Open the Run dialog box, type services.msc to open Windows Services console. Double click on the **Foxit Reader/ Phantom
>      Service** to open the Properties dialog. Set Start-up type to
>      **Disabled**, click on Apply and click on Stop.

---

> #### For IT Admins
>
> **Option 1. Use GPO**
>
> Use GPO templates listed at http://cdn01.foxitsoftware.com/pub/foxit/GPO/enu/ , pick up and
>   download an appropriate file. Once you have the GPO template set in
>   place, implement the following steps.
>
> 1. Open Group Policy Editor, go to Computer or User Configuration ->
>      Administrative Templates -> Classic Administrative Templates (ADM)
>      -> Foxit PhanotomPDF 8.0 -> ConnectedPDF -> double click on Disable ConnectedcPDF Features -> check the option Enable -> click on
>      Ok to
>      apply the change.
> 2. Stop Foxit Service: Open Command Prompt and type the following:
>
>    `net stop FoxitPhantomService` OR `net stop FoxitReaderService`
>
>    `Sc config foxitPhantomSerivce start=disabled` OR `Sc config foxitReaderSerivce start=disabled`
>
> **Option 2. Use XML file**
>
> An XML file to force settings on users, you can create and distribute an XML file to a dedicated folder on Users’
>   machine to turn cPDF features off. Below are steps:
>
> - Distribute the XML file into “C:Program Files (x86)Foxit SoftwareFoxit PhantomPDFProfStore”.
> - Restart PhantomPDF, cPDF features shall have been disabled.
> - Stop Foxit Service:
> - Type the following:
>
>   `net stop FoxitPhantomService` OR `net stop FoxitReaderService`
>
>   `Sc config foxitPhantomSerivce start=disabled` OR `Sc config foxitReaderSerivce start=disabled`
>
> **Option 3. Use MST file with MSI Installer**
>
> If you want to disable cPDF features when deploying MSI installer file, you can use the MST file to implement it.
>
> - Download an appropriate version of Foxit Customization Tool (FCT)
>     from here.
>     https://help.foxitsoftware.com/kb/available-customization-tools.php
> - Run  FCT, click on File to open the appropriate MSI installer file.
> - In the General tab, click on Browse button under Replace ProfStore.xml to add the XML file (ProfStore .XML). See Use XML file
>     section for how to creating an XML file.
> - Everything is done, click
>     on File > Save to save current settings as .mst file.
> - Use the
>     following command to apply MST file `msiexec /i Setup.msi
>     TRANSFORMS=xxx.mst`
>
> Please Note: cPDF service may be still running in the background. You
>   can disable it by launching Command Prompt, and type  the following
>   stop service:
>
> `net stop FoxitPhantomService` OR `net stop FoxitReaderService`
>
> `Sc config foxitPhantomSerivce start=disabled` OR `Sc config foxitReaderService start=disabled`

Source [How to turn off ConnectedPDF (cPDF) ?](https://help.foxitsoftware.com/kb/how-to-turn-off-connectedpdf.php)

Comment: "I found this on Foxit's own site". As it stands this is plagiarism. **You must include a source link and block quote any copied text**. Please read [How to reference material written by others](http://superuser.com/help/referencing).

Comment: Hi @DavidPostill, I'd like to differ on that. The intent of the post is superbly crisp and clear. Specifically, none of us are in the habit of placing footnotes around our conversations. Besides links to the original creators sites abound in the post itself.  If originality of research were the other criteria, none of us would be qualified to answer these questions. Since acknowledgement is already given where due. The charge of plagiarism is not applicable here.

Comment: **You must include a source link and block quote any copied text**. This is not negotiable. I've fixed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are somehow hosting the software on your server to your client-users then, uninstall and reinstall doing the following:

Check "Custom Installation" on the initial screen:
[image: Installation Screenshot1]

Uncheck "ConnectedPDF" (and whatever other extensions and plugins that are undesirable) from the 'select components to install' screen:
[image: Installation Screenshot2]

Obviously, this same method will work on a client to client basis, as well (but, that would be wrist-slittingly tedious, if you have a LOT of users....)